# Android App stops with a Keeps Stopping message

Tags: kotlin-android-extensions

I am following the instructions at [CodeLabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app-kotlin/index.html#6) to add the countMe function

But when I run it I get a "My First App keeps stopping" message.

```
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import android.widget.Toast.*

class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun countMe (view: View) {
        // Get the text view
        val showCountTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

        // Get the value of the text view.
        val countString = showCountTextView.text.toString()

        // Convert value to a number and increment it
        var count: Int = Integer.parseInt(countString)
        count++

        // Display the new value in the text view.
        showCountTextView.text = count.toString();
    }
}
```

the layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/FirstHello"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:id="@+id/textView"/>
    <Button
            android:text="@string/toast"
            android:onClick="toastMe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toast_button" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

    <Button
            android:text="Count"
            android:onClick="countMe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/count_button" android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toast_button" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="48dp" android:layout_marginStart="48dp"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Random"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/random_button" android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="72dp" android:layout_marginRight="72dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I run the app and click the button the application stops.

Comment: I did extract the TextView text into a resource. Perhaps that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I changed the text to contain a number